# Is it possible to convert Azure function to Azure webjob

Tags: azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Is it possible to convert Azure function to Azure Webjob? as example, can following azure function covert to azure job?

```
public class Functions
    {
        // This function will get triggered/executed when a new message is written 
        // on an Azure Queue called queue.
        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("testsbqueuexxx") ] string message, TextWriter log)
        {
            log.WriteLine($"[WebJobNotificationProcessor-]-{message}");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: why would you want that? You can have your Function run on an existing App Service, too. Have a look at the hosting options you have for Functions in [Azure Functions scale and hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale).

Second: I don't think you can, since the trigger is not available for WebJobs. There are two types of webjobs: continuous and triggered. As far as a triggered webjob go, it...

> Starts only when triggered manually or on a schedule.
>
> Source: [Run background tasks with WebJobs in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create)

You *could*, of course, do away with the trigger and move to a continuous webjobs that polls the queue, but you will be throwing away a lot of stuff that the Functions runtime abstracts away for you like connecting to the Service Bus, checking the queue, managing locks and completing or deferring messages.

Comment: even with continuous running webjobs you can have a service bus trigger which will be creating its own listener.